# search file for string(s)

Tags: python

I am learning Python and am currently trying to create a script that searches the 1,000 most common words (as given [here](http://splasho.com/upgoer5/phpspellcheck/dictionaries/1000.dicin)) for a string given by user input.

So far, I have been able to, given a SINGLE word via raw_input, search that list (saved as .txt), and determine if the user input is in the file. However, I can't seem to figure out how to search the text and simply reply with either "Word is in 1,000 words" or "Word is NOT in the list".  I can only reply "word is not in list" for each line.

I am basically trying to create a script that would compare a user's input and see if all words in that input are in the 1,000 most common words (obviously prompted by [this](http://xkcd.com/1133/) XKCD comic).  Ultimately, I would like to 'recreate' what [this website](http://splasho.com/upgoer5/) does, but with a Python script.

Here's what I have so far:

```
cmnwords = open('C:\\Users\\[username]\\1000words.txt')
uInput = raw_input("What is your sentence? ")


def checkInput():
    for line in cmnwords:
        if uInput not in line:
            print uInput, "is not in the most common words"
        else:
            print uInput, "is OKAY! :D", line
checkInput()
```

The above kind of works - but it replies after EACH LINE. I just want to know basically "Yes, the user's input string is in the most common word list" or "No! [word] is not in the most common words, try again", without having to see that answer for every line.

(Also, how can I search for exactly the user input? If you run the above, if the user input is "you", it thinks "young", "yourself", and others are okay.  No - I just want to find exactly "you".)

Does this make sense? Thanks for any help and please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: For the second part of your question, the reason its doing that is because the letters `'you'` are in the string `'young'` and you are asking Python, quite literally `if 'you' in 'young'` which is obviously a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

Let `cmnwords` be a list of strings containing the 1000 most common words.

Then you can test if a given string is in the most common words using `word in cmnwords`.

```
cmnwords = open('C:\\Users\\[username]\\1000words.txt').read().splitlines()
# cmnwords = ['a', 'able', ...]
uInput = raw_input("What is your word? ")

def checkInput():
    # optionally you can use uInput.lower() below so that the search is case-insensitive
    if uInput in cmnwords:
        print uInput, "is not in the most common words"
    else:
        print uInput, "is OKAY! :D", line

checkInput()
```

This also solves the problem of partial matches with 'you', 'yourself' as you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you're searching for the entire input string. It the user inputs `"You will not go to space today"`, then your program will only succed if the exact string `"You will not go to space today"` is somewhere in cmnwords. What you want to do is split the input into words, possibly like this:
    words = [match.lower() for match in re.findall(r"[a-z']", uInput)]

Your second problem is that you print `is OKAY! :D` after each line of `1000words.txt` is checked. Wait until you check the entire file, *then* print `OKAY`.